# Why is Spring Security permitAll not working?

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

Here is my configuration. I want any URL that has ADMIN in it's part to be accesible only by admins, everything else - free to use. But it gives"error": "Unauthorized" for unlogged users.

```
    @Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
            .csrf().disable()
            .httpBasic()
            .and()
            .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
            .and()
            .headers().frameOptions().disable()
            .and()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("**/admin/**").hasRole(Role.ADMIN.getAuthority())
            .anyRequest().permitAll();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Copy/pasted your config in a new project and it works as expected with one modification, more exactly replacing `.antMatchers` with `.mvcMatchers`.

Using that `.antMatchers` instead of `.mvcMatchers` is a common pitfall, as it will produce unexpected results sometimes. In my version of Spring, for example, your `.antMatchers("**/admin/**")` dosen't match `/s2/admin/s2`, because the matcher dosen't start with `/`. This matching fails in the `AntPathMatcher.class` from Spring.

By using `.mvcMatchers` you use the same web path resolver as your controllers.